Issue in API Management Policies artifact on Standard V2 or Basic V2
I made a policie artifact for an api in API Management, but had a problem.
Error message detail
I tried many times to find the issue, but couldn't. I perceived a behavior when I change from Standard V2 to Consumption or Developer. It's worked! Probality, the version v2 have a problem.
Look at the code below.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("access-token"))">
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers["access-token"][0].StartsWith("Bearer "))">
                        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="validationResponse">
                            <set-url>https://its-example-url</set-url>
                            <set-method>POST</set-method>
                            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                                <value>@(context.Request.Headers["access-token"][0].Replace("Bearer ", ""))</value>
                            </set-header>
                        </send-request>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                                <value>text/plain</value>
                            </set-header>
                            <set-body>Esta faltando o Bearer no valor da chave 'access-token', na header!</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.ContainsKey("access_token"))">
                        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="validationResponse">
                            <set-url>https://its-example-url</set-url>
                            <set-method>POST</set-method>
                            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                                <value>@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("access_token", ""))</value>
                            </set-header>
                        </send-request>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                                <value>text/plain</value>
                            </set-header>
                            <set-body>Esta faltando o parametro access_token!</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@{
                var response = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<IResponse>("validationResponse", null);
                return (int)response.StatusCode != 200;
            }">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="@{
                        var response = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<IResponse>("validationResponse", null);
                        return (int)response.StatusCode;
                    }" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@{
                        var response = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<IResponse>("validationResponse", null);
                        return response.Body.As<string>();
                    }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>Authorization</header>
                <header>access-token</header>
                <header>Content-Type</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

I tried to use Basic V2 but had same problem. I need to understand with this code have a problem or the version. If this proble is the code, how can I resolve ?
Thks!

You would normally get this error if you tried using character < in an attribute value, for example see line 40 below:

The code you shared doesn't have this issue. I tried saving it in my API Management service (Premium Tier), and the error didn't appear.
Please double-check the code on your side. Any occurrences of < inside attribute values can be replaced with &lt;
